# Dual booting Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 5577 using the D: drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I would like to try out Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 5577.

The problem is the low SSD free space on C: (20 GB). However, my D: drive (normal HDD) has 600 GB of free space. Can I partition my D: drive and dual boot Ubuntu from that?

I don't want to take any risks or end up bricking my laptop. I also don't want to lose the data on the drive.

Could someone please help me with a proper process on how to do it as I could not find much specific to my problem.